# What is faster? angular expressions or controller code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

After some time programming with angular a question has occurred to me:

What is "faster"/"lighter to process" the ng-xxxx statments or doing code in the controller and why?
An example would be:

In controller:

```
var aid= document.getElementById("Aid");
if( $scope.Mode == "mode1") aid.style.visibility = 'visible'; else aid.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

In html:

```
 <div id="Aid" ng-if="Mode== 'mode1'">
```

In my current project I've found that using ng-if makes the app response "better" but before making a change on my style of coding when I have to hide elements I would like to know more

Comment: I don't think the can be a definitive answer for the question. It depends on each and every case. When in doubt, measure :)

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: The manual dom manipulation you have there, it absolutely should not be in the controller. That's what directives are for (`ng-if`, in your case). BTW, `ng-if` is not equivalent to flipping `visibility`.

Comment: ^ Yeah, I'd do `ng-show="Mode == 'mode1'"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is "faster"/"lighter to process" the ng-xxxx statments or doing code in the controller and why? An example would be:

As one commenter to your question said:

> "I don't think the can be a definitive answer for the question. It depends on each and every case..."

Unless you're processing 10000+ rows on a table, all with several angular built-in directives and {{bindings}}, you're not going to really see a performance hit.  And if you are, then there are better ways to performance tweak the UI (e.g. pagination, lazy-load, infinite scrolling) while still utilizing tried-and-true tools like the built-in directives.

I think the more important question you should be asking is "why am I going against best practices by doing XYZ".  Using the controller code you proposed:

```
var aid= document.getElementById("Aid");
if( $scope.Mode == "mode1") aid.style.visibility = 'visible'; else aid.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

...is absolutely going against any angular best practices and **should be avoided**.  You already have a directive for this in the supplied `ng-if` directive.